# time sampling of a Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

In Sheldon Ross, one paragraph has a heading "time sampling of a Poission process" and it describes that each arrival we toss a biased coin with $p(t)$ being bias prob.Then the process generated is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda(t)p(t)$. How can this be time sampling ?

I thought that generating individual exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$ was sufficient. What exactly is meant by "time sampling" ?

Comment: I think time sampling in this context just means that you are sampling a random fraction of the parent process. The claim is that the result is also a Poisson process. So if the parent process has a mean rate of 10 events per hour and you randomly sample, say, 20% of the parent events, the result will be a Poisson process with a mean rate of 2 per hour.

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced from @soakley's comment:

> Time sampling in this context just means that one is sampling a random fraction of the parent process. The claim is that the result is also a Poisson process. So if the parent process has a mean rate of 10 events per hour and one randomly samples, say, 20% of the parent events, the result will be a Poisson process with a mean rate of 2 per hour.